# How to produce a list of my own deleted answers?

Tags: support, deletion, deleted-answers

From a [previous thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562/is-it-possible-to-find-deleted-questions-via-the-tools-menu-if-so-how), it seems that the functionality to list deleted answers has been removed. Is this true? What if I only want to see a list of my own deleted answers?

Comment: Unfortunately, the request [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/) has `status-declined` despite having all-around support of the user base (current vote count +465). All we can do is bookmark the answers before deleting them.

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently this feature was added to the SE.

You can get a list of your own deleted posts by clicking [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20deleted%3A1).

You can do it only if you have at least 10000 reputation.

---

Extension, 2021: now everybody can get a list of their deleted questions/answers by clicking the "Deleted questions" / "Deleted answers" link at the bottom of the "Questions" ("Answers") tab of your profile. Thank you, SE!

Comment: Now the users below 10k can find their own deleted/question through their profile, too: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Wow, that is a wonderful new development! Thank you very much. I extended the answer.

Answer (score 11):

The answer by iostream007 is actually valid now: the profile tab `/votes/deletion` shows you all the votes to delete that you cast, on your own posts and on the posts of others. This is the result of an [ancient feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140328/259867) (July 2012)  fulfilled recently.

Alternatively, open the `/answers` tab of the profile and click "deleted recent answers" at the bottom. As the name suggests, this shows only relatively recent answers (60 days, if I remember correctly).

Comment: Good news!$\phantom{}$

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to do that. Only moderators can see deleted posts in user profiles, regular users can't see them.

Comment: To be clear, +1 for presenting the information, not for the information itself (which is sad).

Answer (score 3):

The best I could do with data.SE was to produce the list of questions which have at least one deleted answer **and** do not have any non-deleted answers. There are two versions of the query: all questions, and questions with a particular tag.

- [Questions with a deleted answer and no other answers](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/121592/questions-with-a-deleted-answer-and-no-other-answers)
- [Questions with a deleted answer (and no other answers), by tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/121593/questions-with-a-deleted-answer-and-no-other-answers-by-tag)

The query does not see the questions with both deleted and non-deleted answers. It also does not know the author(s) of the deleted answer(s).

But I think the lists may still be of value; these tend to be non-straightforward problems.

---

Here is a hopeful sign: SE is testing the possibility of showing users the list of their recently deleted **questions**. See [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/). I don't see any link to this list on the user profile, but the feature appears to work if you navigate to

`math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/xxxxx`

where xxxxx is your user number (e.g., $1551$). My list is empty since I did not ask any questions on main; hopefully someone with recent deleted questions can test this and confirm if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although they are not what I need, the three links you provided are interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

In your profile go to "votes" tab.then you will see some sub tab like "all,upvote,downvote,"here in deletion and undeletion you can see your deleted answers.

Comment: Thanks, but apparently, the "deleted" option in the "votes" tab only lists those answers that you have once deleted ***but reopened later***. Answers that remain deleted are not shown.

Comment: @user1551 That behavior was changed; see my answer.